# How to make newsboat autorefresh every minute?

Tags: software-recommendation, rss

I always have newsboat open in a terminal at the corner of my desktop. I would like newsboat to auto refresh every minute or so so i don't have to do it manually. Is there a way to do this?

I understand that creating a config file in the directory makes newsboat refresh the feeds when you open newsboat. But I would like newsboat to continue to refresh the feeds, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the application according to its documentation.

Create two files with urls and options. Below is minimal reproducible example:

```
echo "https://askubuntu.com/feeds" > ~/.newsboat/urls

cat << EOF > ~/.newsboat/config
auto-reload yes
reload-time 1
EOF
```

Then run NewsBoat with `newsboat -r` . It will refresh every 1 minute.

---

See `man newsboat` for details locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/newsboat.1.html).